# CString + operator or Format

Tags: visual-c++

I have a sample code like this:

```
CString A = _T("abc");
CString B = _T("xyz");
CString res;
```

now to concat these two above strings, which one should I prefer:

`res = A + _T(" ") + B;`

or

```
res.Format(_T("%s %s"), A, B);
```

Comment: The first one can go well.

Comment: I know both are okay, but my concern is which one is optimal. As the first will make 2 +operator calls and them with each call, it will call c-tor and distributors. Plus an additional call of assignment operator. Where as, I am not sure how the second will act. So what I wanted to know was, which  one is optimal?

Comment: If you are going for such detailing then both will work fine for cases where inputs are small. But for larger sizes to be dealt with and keeping in mind the processing time the second one could go in handy as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a sample function and ran the the bellow code

```
CString str1 = _T("abc");
CString str2 = _T("xyz");
CString strRes;
DWORD dwTickCount = GetTickCount();
const int LoopCount = 1000000;
for(int nIdx = 0; nIdx < LoopCount; nIdx++)
{
    strRes = str1 + _T(" ") + str2;
}
dwTickCount = GetTickCount() - dwTickCount;
```

The value of dwTickCount was 2656. But while checking the second case,

```
CString str1 = _T("abc");
CString str2 = _T("xyz");
CString strRes;
DWORD dwTickCount = GetTickCount();
const int LoopCount = 1000000;
for(int nIdx = 0; nIdx < LoopCount; nIdx++)
{
    strRes.Format(_T("%s %s"), str1, str2);
}
dwTickCount = GetTickCount() - dwTickCount;
```

The value of dwTickCount was 453 only.
Hence I can say, the Format approach is about 6 times faster.

Comment: Did you profile this in an optimized release build? In my test there is around a 10% difference. `GetTickCount` is also not the best function to use for timing things as it doesn't have very good resolution. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @RetiredNinja, I agree that GetTickCount is not optimal for measuring the performance, but still it gives some good idea about the execution time taken. I had used the an un-optimized build initially but even with the optimized release build also took 50% more time at my end.